# Assigning sub-lists of a list a name more efficiently

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, loops, for-loop

I have assigned `sub lists` a name from a `large list`, as followed:

```
AB, CD, EF, GH, IJ, KL, MN, OP, QR, ST, UV, WQ, YZ, AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, FF, GG = large_list[0], large_list[1], large_list[2], large_list[3], large_list[4], large_list[5], large_list[6], large_list[7], large_list[8], large_list[9], large_list[10], large_list[11], large_list[12], large_list[13], large_list[14], large_list[15], large_list[16], large_list[17], large_list[18], large_list[19]
```

This seems pretty unpractical, hence was wondering whether there is a method that is considered more efficient or even shorter for that matter.

I'm assuming some form a loop would help? e.g. `for sub_list in large_list: ???`

Comment: Does the left side of the assignment also need to be automated? The left side is pretty easy as Python does it for you automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have use a dictionary for that

```
li = ["AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ", "KL", "MN", "OP", "QR", "ST", "UV", "WQ", "YZ", "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG" ]
dicti = {}
for subList,key in zip(large_list,li):
  dicti[key] = subList
```

you can use dict comprehension as well:

```
li = ["AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ", "KL", "MN", "OP", "QR", "ST", "UV", "WQ", "YZ", "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG" ]
dicti = dicti = {key: sub_ist for key, sub_ist in zip(li, large_list)}
```

As Chris_Rands wrote at the comment, you can simply do:

```
dict(zip(li,large_list))
```

Comment: Agree that dictionary is the right way to go here, but you can simply use `dict(zip(li,large_list))`

Comment: Correct, i will add it to the answer, thanks @Chris_Rands

Comment: Why a dictionary over a list in this case?

Comment: @BenF97 Dictionaries are built for this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's unpacking abilities:

```
L = list(range(10))
a, b = L[:2]
```

For your case:

```
AB, CD, EF, GH, IJ, KL, MN, OP, QR, ST, UV, WQ, YZ, AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, FF, GG  = large_list[:20]
```

For better readability, you can break lines, using parenthesis:

```
large_list = list(range(100))
(AB, CD, EF, GH, IJ, KL, MN, OP, QR, ST, UV, WQ, 
 YZ, AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, FF, GG)  = large_list[:20]
```

Now `AB` is `0` and `GG` is `19`

Comment: @AriGold That wouldn't help, the point is to truncate the list so it's only as long as the number of variables being assigned to (which is 20). If `large_list` is longer than 20 then you want to reduce it to 20 items.

Comment: Why is `list(range(100))` necessary? It seems to work fine without.

Comment: I am using Python 3.  While you can slice `range` objects, the OP asked for a list.  So it works without `list` but makes it closer the  question with it. In Python 2 `range() ` returns a list. Converting into a list does not hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Python has something called tuple unpacking, where you can assign multiple values from a collection. It 'unpacks' the collection to turn it into all its parts. Here's a simple example:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3]
a, b, c = numbers
# a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]
# a = 1, b = 2, c = 3
```

So you can do your method just by having the list name on the right:

```
AB, CD, EF, GH, IJ, KL, MN, OP, QR, ST, UV, WQ, YZ, AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, FF, GG = large_list
```

Though if `large_list` has more or less items in it than you're assigning to, you will get errors. (ie. if `large_list` has 21 items but you're trying to assign to 20). You can mitigate it being too large by using `large_list[:20]` to at least only take the first 20 items in the list.